# Rewrite URL parameter to new path

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

How can I rewrite `example.com/category/?=shoes` to `example.com/category/shoes`. This is for a Wordpress site

Comment: Is this for apache2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following rule :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/shoe/?$ /category?=shoe [L]
```

If the /shoe perameter is dynamic, you can use this :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^category/([^/]+)/?$ /category?=$1 [L]
```